# MapBox: Legend not working when full screen

Tags: vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a legend inside the map, is working fine when the map is not full screen, but when the map is full screen the legend is not showing.

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Open the map and see the legend is present and working fine
2. Click full screen icon
3. The legend is not present
4. Click full screen icon again to remove the full screen, now the legend is present and working fine

**Expected behavior**

The legend should work fine when full screen.

**Screenshots**

Normal screen, working fine:

[image]

Full screen, not showing the legend:

[image]

**Additional context**

Code example available on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-wave-c3qmg. You should open the link https://c3qmg.csb.app/ on another page to be able to see the fullscreen icon.

Code extract:

```html
<template>
  <!-- MapBox map -->
  <MglMap
    ref="customMap"
    :mapStyle="map.mapStyle"
    :zoom="map.zoom"
    :center="map.center"
    :attributionControl="false"
    @mousemove="mouseMoved"
    @click="mapClick"
  >
    <MglFullscreenControl position="top-left" />
    <MglNavigationControl position="top-left" />
    <MglScaleControl position="bottom-left" />

    <!-- Custom html legend, using the feature selected-->
    <MapLegend :feature="selectedFeature" />

    <div
      v-for="geoJsonLayer in getGeoJsonLayers.mapLayers"
      :key="geoJsonLayer.id"
    >
      <!-- Fill geojson -->
      <MglGeojsonLayer
        :sourceId="geoJsonLayer.sourceId"
        :source="geoJsonLayer.source"
        :layerId="geoJsonLayer.layerId"
        :layer="geoJsonLayer.layer"
      />

      <!-- Source is not needed but the source id is needed :) when you are using an already defined source above -->
      <!-- Outline geojson -->
      <MglGeojsonLayer
        :sourceId="`${geoJsonLayer.outlineLayerId}-source`"
        :layerId="geoJsonLayer.outlineLayerId"
        :layer="geoJsonLayer.outlineLayer"
      />
    </div>
  </MglMap>
</template>
```

Node packages installed:

```
├── @highcharts/map-collection@1.1.3
├── @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.2.3
├── @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.2.3
├── @vue/cli-service@4.2.3
├── axios@0.19.2
├── babel-eslint@10.1.0
├── bootstrap-vue@2.21.2
├── bootstrap@4.6.0
├── core-js@3.9.1
├── d3-drag@2.0.0
├── d3-force@2.1.1
├── d3@6.6.1
├── eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2
├── eslint@6.8.0
├── highcharts-vue@1.3.5
├── highcharts@8.2.2
├── leaflet.heat@0.2.0
├── leaflet@1.7.1
├── mapbox-gl@0.53.1
├── moment-timezone@0.5.33
├── proj4@2.7.2
├── qs@6.10.1
├── vue-axios@2.1.5
├── vue-i18n@8.24.2
├── vue-mapbox@0.4.1
├── vue-router@3.5.1
├── vue-template-compiler@2.6.12
├── vue@2.6.12
└── vuex@3.6.2
```

Comment: You should host the code on codepen or similar to assist investigation.

Comment: @SteveBennett Post edited with the code on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-wave-c3qmg. You should open the link https://c3qmg.csb.app on another page to be able to see the fullscreen icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the [Mapbox GL JS fullscreen control](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#fullscreencontrol) only makes the map container itself full screen. Nothing else on the screen will be visible.

So you need to pass the container element through to Vue-Mapbox's `MglFullScreenControl` as the `container` parameter, along these lines:

```
  <div id="mycontainer">
    <MglMap
      :accessToken="accessToken"
      :mapStyle="mapStyle"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      ref="map"
      class="default-map-xl"
    >
      <MglFullscreenControl position="top-left" :container="containerElement"/>
      <MapBoxLegend :selectedFeature="selectedFeature" />
    </MglMap>
```

There's probably a better way to do this, but you can set that element as a data property once your component mounts.

```
  data() {
    return {
      //...
      containerElement: null
    };
  },  
  mounted() {
    this.containerElement = document.getElementById('mycontainer')
  }
```

I forked your code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-tree-uj9l9?file=/src/components/MapExample.vue).

Answer (score 0):

for somebody who work with angular or etc.:

```
mapInstance.addControl(new FullscreenControl({container: document.querySelector('body')}), "top-left");
```